# echo TXT variable from other PHP file

Tags: php, include, echo

I want somethong like this:
File PEOPLE.PHP

```
<?php

$name_surname1='Wiliam Smith';
$name _surname2='Adam BlaBla';

?>
```

other PHP File - RECORDS.PHP

```
<?php include 'people.php';?>
<html>
<body>
<div><? echo $ name_surname1;</div>
<div><? echo $ name_surname2;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, tell me What is wrong in PEOPLE.PHP or how to achieve my task? I am totally new in this field. Thank you very much for your support

Comment: it seems that I did a mistake before, Everything working...

Comment: Missing closing `?>` on both of those echo statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an unexpected space in the `$name_surname2` variable.

Put this into your people.php :

```
$name_surname1='Wiliam Smith';
$name_surname2='Adam BlaBla';
```

Then, to access your vars, do not put spaces between `$` and the variable name, and close your PHP tags.

```
<div><? echo $name_surname1; ?></div>
<div><? echo $name_surname2; ?></div>
```